# how to empty a dependent backbone.js collection?

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I have a backbone collection that is dependent on another collection in my Rails application.  I want to make sure that the view that displays the dependent collection is emptied out and the dependent collections is 'reset' it its view as well as corresponding records from the server are deleted. Is there an easy way to do so or do I have to loop through the collection and fire off model.destroy calls for all models in the dependent collection when the last record from the existing collection is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone Collections have a `reset()` [(docs)](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) method that will take a list of models as an argument. If you pass no argument, it will empty the entire Collection. However, this will not by default remove the models themselves from the server as you probably saw.

There's also a `sync()` [(docs)](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) on the Collection that will sync the collection (or all the models in the collection) to the server. Of course if you've run `reset()` the Collection is now empty, so that doesn't really help.

In the end I think that you will have to loop through the Collection to destroy each model (unless you want to take a serverside approach to limit your calls), but you should be able to extend your Collection and add a `destroyCollection()` method, or simply extend the already present `reset` collection to call the `destroy()` on the models before it resets the collection to empty.

If this doesn't help maybe provide a higher up example of what you're trying to achieve and maybe there's an even simpler way?

Comment: thanks for your response.  I am going to accept your answer.  It seems like it is the lack of my Backbone knowledge that is preventing me from successfully implementing a solution.  But I am going to post a detailed higher up example in a separate question with my code that hopefully will enable yourself and/or people like you to be able to answer my question more effectively.